# how to describe a person in office live by `Information Asymmetry`

Tags: business-language

if a person work in a office at a firm.

He reports his manager the information best for him, sometimes lies to his manager.
He tells his subordinate staff the information best for him, sometimes lies .

His manger thinks he is doing great job and take all the hard work,because manager doesn't know the full picture.

subordinate staff is doing the all the hard work and doesn't earn the credit he/she deserve.

he is using `Information Asymmetry` to live happily in the office .

Any english phase to describe this behavior or person ?

Comment: "Asymmetry" seems an odd word to use for that situation.

Comment: I hope the motivation for this question isn't to call someone names, even behind their back, or otherwise engage in conflict with them. If you are experiencing this situation, it would be better to ask a question on [workplace.se] on how to cope with the situation.

Comment: There are many phrases used to describe both this behavior and person, but none are used in polite company. Given you tagged this question as "politics" and "management", this isn't the appropriate board. As suggested, see workplace.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in workplace.SE, and has likely been answered there many times. As an EL&U question, it fails to include information on how the word or phrase will be used.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase is "middle management"! Though the way you describe the behaviour of this person, they don't sound particularly nice, this is the overall theme of middle management. Get the most out of your subordinates, take the credit for their work from your superiors.

Regarding his lies, there are lots of phrases, mostly insults, that I would use. Mostly he is being "conniving"/"deceitful"/"dishonest".

Comment: Isn't the question more about the lying behaviour than the position in the hierarchy? It's not the theme of middle management to lie to everybody.

Comment: thanks , 'middle management' is neutral word while doesn't reflect the misbehavior .but I'm appreciate your reply.